# Stop VCL Child Controls from Inheriting Parent Popup Menu

Tags: delphi, inheritance, parent, delphi-2007, popupmenu

I have a Delphi 2007 VCL TPanel with a TPopupMenu assigned to it. There are some TEdit controls on the panel.  The edits inherit the popup menu of the parent panel.  I want to not allow this popup inheriting, so the edits will show the default Windows TEdit popup menu with Copy, Cut, Paste, etc., but have not found a way to do it yet.  There doesn't appear to be a "ParentPopupMenu" type property to set which controls inherit it from the parent component.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try setting the PopupMenu's AutoPopup property to False, and then manually Popup() the menu when needed, since as in the TPanel's OnContextMenu event.

Comment: Thanks, this OnContextPopup code seems to work:

    var
      Control: TControl;
    begin
      Control := FindVCLWindow(Mouse.CursorPos) ;
      if Control = MyPanel then begin
        MyMenu.Popup(Mouse.CursorPos.X, Mouse.CursorPos.Y);
        Handled := True;
      end;
    end;

Answer (score 4):

This is [QC#54286: Parent-PopupMenu overrides standard context menu](http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=54286).  Andreas Hausladen's [VCL Fix Pack](http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/?page_id=288) fixes the issue so it works the way you're expecting it to.

Comment: Thanks for the links.  It is good to know I'm not alone in considering this a bug.  Hopefully Embarcadero will eventually agree.  I decided to go with the AutoPopup fix, since I wanted the simplest possible fix, and I only need it on one form.